# How can I create a circle with elements at the very end of its axis?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I'll be using some SVGs that will be those avatars on the axis. For now all I need is a hint on how to set those avatars at the very end of every axis.

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

This the code I have so far:

```css
body {
  background-color: #de4e40;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.squareLoader {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='squareLoader'></div>
```

And here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/bzKPQy?editors=1100) in case you want to take a look.

Is there any guide or someone can help me on how to achieve this?
I can use flexbox and also I am using React Native. Just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make `squareLoader` a relative parent
- Position element in corners using `translate`, `top`, `left`
- Share styles wherever possible
- Store repeated offset value in `CSS` variable

[image]

```css
:root {
  --offset: -1.4em;
}

body {
  background-color: #de4e40;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.squareLoader {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.squareLoader img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
}


.one, .three {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.two, .four {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.one {
  top: var(--offset);
}

.two {
  right: var(--offset);
}

.three {
  bottom: var(--offset);
}

.four {
  left: var(--offset);
}
```

```html
<div class="squareLoader">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/190/190675.svg" alt="" class="one">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/190/190675.svg" alt="" class="two">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/190/190675.svg" alt="" class="three">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/190/190675.svg" alt="" class="four">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uf2t5p6r/3/

Comment: I like the use of translate, nice!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your post correctly, you want to place SVG images on the North, South, East, and West points of a circle with CSS; It is definitely possible to do this with CSS, but it depends completely on the size of the container and the size of the images being used.

The example circle you provided has a set height and width, so assuming that your SVG images are also a set size and do not change with page size you can do something like this.

```
body {
  background-color: #de4e40;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.squareLoader {
  /* added 'position: relative', because parent elements of absolute positioned elements have to be positioned to prevent mayhem */
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.avatarN {
  top: -25px;
}

.avatarS {
  top: 175px;
}

.avatarE {
  left: 175px;
}

.avatarW {
  left: -25px;
}
```

and the HTML with `.avatar` `<div>`s (you can stick the SVG images inside these divs):

```
<div class='squareLoader'>
    <div class="avatar avatarN"></div>
    <div class="avatar avatarS"></div>
    <div class="avatar avatarE"></div>
    <div class="avatar avatarW"></div>
</div>
```

In the previous example all four avatar `<div>`s are given a height and width of `50px`.

`.avatarN` has a `top` position of `-25px` because that is half of the image's height and a `left` position of `75px` (half of `.squareLoader`'s width minus half of the image's width).

`.avatarW` has a `top` position of `75px` (half of `.squareLoader`'s height minus half of the image's height) and a `left` position of `25px`, which is half of the image's height.

And so on for the other divs.

If you are going to make your `.squareLoader` `<div>` resize based on the page size, and the images resize based on page size, you can use the calc() CSS function which can be used anywhere a length unit is allowed in CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

w3Schools has a pretty decent cursory explanation of all the units allowed in CSS:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

And also, here's their page on position values in CSS as well:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Whether or not you are using flexbox, you'll still have to use the position property to get the images where you want them.

Answer (score 1):

One idea to create this is to consider only background and it will be easier to handle:

```css
body {
  background-color: #de4e40;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.squareLoader {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1069) top center,
    url(https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1069) bottom center,
    url(https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1069) left center,
    url(https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=1069) right center,
    /*the circle*/
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, 
      #fff calc(100% - 32px),#000 calc(100% - 30px),
      #000 calc(100% - 30px),#000 calc(100% - 20px),
      transparent calc(100% - 18px));
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='squareLoader'></div>
```